# css z-index changes during opacity animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a very simple page, there are a few stacks of divs and each div has and image inside of it.

Each stack will fadeIn depending on the scroll position,  the top stack has an object that overlaps the bottom stack and for some reason during the animation, the z-index changes.

here's the JSBIN, try clicking the fadeIn/fadeOut button and notice how the plate briefly went behind the bottom stack when it's transitioned.

http://jsbin.com/wefediti/1/

please help.

Comment: It's inlcuded when you run it. Look for the top right where it says Edit. It's a form of fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since your `jQuery.each()` and therefore the fading animation will be processed synchronously,  it is not possible with your approach to make them fade at the very same time.

I suggest you combine those images in the same `div` and fade them if it is possible for you:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DK7KM)**

Comment: On the design there are more stacks which fades in sequentially, so I can't change how the HTML is structured.

Isn't there a way to get around it? without employing hacks?

Answer (score 0):

It's a thing of positioning of your divs

I edited. All you need to do is stack your divs right and then re-edit your absolute position. But it works

[EDITED CODE](http://jsbin.com/wefediti/2/edit)

Let me be more specific.

change the order of your divs liek so:

```
<div class="page1">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BleOC.jpg">
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

and that will fix you z-index problem. I made a different call for each div from the JS as well, But that was for testing purposes. I think you're fine with one call

I made the positioning edits as well [**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/wefediti/2/edit)

But it seems like everyone is modifying it, so hurry up before someone else messes it up lol

Comment: @badcoder div stacking is very strict unless you wan to alter it with z-index, which in this case is working against you. So you have to go with the primitive way of layering your divs. 

If you have more layers use pseudocode :after and :before to manage some of the layers positioning, but it's a hit and miss and you will have problems with older browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
  function fadePages(num) {  
  $(".page").animate({
    opacity: num
    }, 1000*(num+1));

}
```

do same at same time. It works.